# How to parse specific JSON data in Android?

Tags: android, json

This is my JSON data from a URL:

```
[
  { "title" : "65th Issue", "author": "అశోక్"},
  { "title" : "64th Issue", "author": "రాము" },
  { "title" : "63rd Issue", "author": "శ్రీను" }
]
```

It is looking like a JSONArray but it does not have its name (Array name) to access. Could anyone tell me how can I parse this JSON data in android?

Parsing Code

```
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
char [] charArray = new char[contentLength];
reader.read(charArray);
String responseData = new String(charArray);

try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(responseData);
    for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        String title = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.v(TAG, "JSON EXCEPTION");
}
```

Comment: Just my 2 cents on the matter, but if you are going to get into JSON at any level of complexity I recommend looking at a helper library like GSON. I made what I would consider I mistake of parsing out my own JSON for a while and I regretted it once I started playing with libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String jsonString = ...; //This contains the above mentioned String.
```

For  JSON String, [] denotes an array, an {} denotes an object. In your case, the string starts with a [] thats means its an array, so we first get the JSONArray.

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

Now, if you see, the array has multiple strings beginning and ending with {}, that means that the array has multiple objects. So we run a loop over the array length to extract each object and then the key - value from the object.

```
for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    String title = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
}
```

So, the complete code will be something like this :

```
String jsonString = ...; //This contains the above mentioned String.
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    String title = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
}
```

**Edit 2** :

```
String jsonString = "[\r\n  { \"title\" : \"65th Issue\", \"author\": \"\u0C05\u0C36\u0C4B\u0C15\u0C4D\"},\r\n  { \"title\" : \"64th Issue\", \"author\": \"\u0C30\u0C3E\u0C2E\u0C41\" },\r\n  { \"title\" : \"63rd Issue\", \"author\": \"\u0C36\u0C4D\u0C30\u0C40\u0C28\u0C41\" }\r\n]";

    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            String title = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
            Log.d(LOGTAG, title);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer for the OP?

Comment: @ShivamVerma    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(responseData);                      this is throwing exception.. 
JSONException: if the parse fails or doesn't yield a JSONArray.

Comment: Yeah, isn't it supposed to be that way. You'll need to add try catch block to catch the exception.

Comment: Just use this to parse :    `String teluguContent = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("key_telugu");`

Comment: try{
      JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(responseData);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.v(TAG, "JSON EXCEPTION");
     } its catching the exception.. means the parsing is failed or doesn't yield a JSONArray.. So how to solve this??

Comment: Yeah. Just add other the other parsing code to the try catch block too.

Comment: @ShivamVerma I've added the other parsing code also. It is still throwsing JSONException..

Comment: Can you post your JSONString, the one that you're actually using in the code. And your parsing code too. Please edit the question and add them

Comment: @ShivamVerma I've removed other parsing code and tried to run with only JSONArray Creation line contained in try/catch block..still throwsing same exception.. which means JSONArray Creation line is not working. Could you help me with that??

Comment: Can you post your actual JSON String ? and the parsing code you're using.

Comment: Can you also post the exact exception that you're getting.

Comment: @ShivamVerma I've posted.. please check it.

Comment: Check Edit 2 in the answer : I just ran the code with the given JSON String and it works fine.

Comment: @ShivamVerma  your answer is working... Actually I am unable to retrieve the entire data from the feed. but when I visited the link in browser everything is there.. Is there any limitation on the data size to be transmitted?? I even changed my charArray size to 50000 which is much more than needed.

Comment: @ShivamVerma thanks man. u r amazing.. I'll be delighted if you kindly help me to solve my other quesion also..

Comment: Sure. Post a new question and pass me the link :)